# Flash running in local enviorment

Tags: php, flash, localhost

I am trying to run a local version of a website on my computer for development.  I have mamp installed along with the mysql database.  I am able to go to http://localhost:8888/.... to get to the local copy of the website and everything works great.

The problem comes up when I try to watch a flash video.  The flash video player was custom made by the development team before me and I have no experience in flash.  I need some help in figuring out how to get flash to run of my computer locally.

I have tried changing the global settings(but maybe I did this incorrectly).

Any help would be great, thank you.

(the website is in php with a code igniter framework)

Comment: do you know how to embed a flash video in a webpage? Running locally is not a problem for flash.

Answer (score 1):

If the flash player has dependencies it may have trouble locating these locally.  Check the paths to the external content/dependencies if it has any.